# Prevent my fragment and list from being created every time they are displayed

Tags: android, kotlin, data-binding, android-databinding, android-architecture-navigation

I'm using databinding and fragments with navigation component for the first time in my app. Everything works fine with regard to navigation and loading my list. The problem I have is this:

When I'm in my list and I click on one of the items, I navigate to the item's detail fragment. But **when I return to the list (onBack), the fragment and the list are loaded again, they are re-created.**

What I want to achieve is **that the fragment and therefore the list are not recreated. That they remain in the same state**, so that when I return from the detail I can continue to navigate my list from the point where I left off.

My code:

**Fragment**

```
 class ListFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var viewDataBinding: FragmentListBinding
    private lateinit var adapter: ListAdapter

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        viewDataBinding = FragmentListBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false).apply {
            viewmodel = ViewModelProviders.of(this@ListFragment).get(ListViewModel::class.java)
            lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
        }
        return viewDataBinding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        setupAdapter()
        setupObservers()
    }

    private fun setupObservers() {
        viewDataBinding.viewmodel?.listLive?.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            adapter.updateList(it)
        })

        viewDataBinding.viewmodel?.toastMessage?.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            activity?.longToast(it)
        })
    }

    private fun setupAdapter() {
        val viewModel = viewDataBinding.viewmodel

        if (viewModel != null) {
            adapter = ListAdapter(viewDataBinding.viewmodel!!)
            val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
            list_rv.layoutManager = layoutManager
            list_rv.adapter = adapter
        }
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        viewDataBinding.viewmodel?.fetchList()
    }
}
```

**Fragment layout**

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<data>

    <import type="android.view.View" />

    <variable
        name="viewmodel"
        type="app.example.list.ListViewModel" />
</data>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
         android:id="@+id/list_rv"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:visibility="@{safeUnbox(viewmodel.dataLoading) ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE}" />
          
</RelativeLayout>
```

**View model**

```
class ListViewModel : BaseViewModel() {
val listLive = MutableLiveData<List<Item>>()

fun fetchList() {
    dataLoading.value = true
    ItemRepository.getInstance().getList() { isSuccess, response ->
        dataLoading.value = false

        if (isSuccess) {
            listLive.value = response?.items
            empty.value = false
        } else {
            empty.value = true
        }
    }
}
}
```

**I'm navigating between the list and the item with navigation**

```
itemView.findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_listFragment_to_detailFragment)
```

Comment: So where are you actually calling `fetchList()`? If you're calling it more than once, why are you doing that unless it is because you want to load the data again?

Comment: @ianhanniballake I had forgotten to show where I do the fetchList, check my update in my fragment, I'm doing it in onResume. This is causing the list to update every time, but if I put the fetchList in onViewCreated the same thing would also happen because the fragment is recreated every time I navigate to it.

Comment: @ianhanniballake I think if I could initialize my viewDataBinding in onCreate, that method if called only when created, would make the fetchList there, I could solve my problem. But I didn't see that it could be done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never be reloading your data in a Lifecycle method such as `onResume()` - that's why your data goes back to loading every time you go back to the fragment.

Instead, you should call `fetchList()` just once in your ViewModel's `init` block - this ensures that it runs only once:

```
class ListViewModel : BaseViewModel() {
     val listLive = MutableLiveData<List<Item>>()

      init {
          fetchList()
      }

      fun fetchList() {
           dataLoading.value = true
           ItemRepository.getInstance().getList() { isSuccess, response ->
                dataLoading.value = false

                if (isSuccess) {
                     listLive.value = response?.items
                     empty.value = false
                } else {
                     empty.value = true
                }
           }
      }
 }
```

It isn't clear how your `getList()` method works. How it is written now is generally correct for a single callback. If your `getList()` is actually returning a stream of values that continue to deliver callbacks as the underlying data changes, then you must make sure you unregister that callback in [`onCleared()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModel#onCleared()) (the callback when the ViewModel is destroyed).

Answer (score 1):

You are getting recycle list recreated every time because of the following code -

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    setupAdapter()     //you are setting adapter every time view is getting created
    setupObservers()
}
```

As you are using navigation architecture to navigate, every time you navigate to a destination, previous fragment will be stop() and upon back it will be re-created. Because as of now navigation component doesn't have the backstact [issue](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/issues/530)

But the whole point of using the ViewModel is to not save fragment state and let the ViewModel keep the data. You are using the view model but, you must not set the adapter on recycle view each time.

Simply notify the recycle view list when you get the list from view model.